# How to retrieve statistics from an mbox file?

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to do some statistics on my mail network and I want to find out the top ten people I've sent the most e-mails to and preferably including the numbers from which one is number 1 and which one number 2 etc. I already loaded my 'mbox' file in, but I have no clue how to work with an 'mbox' file and so how to do this.

I imported the mbox file with the following code:

```
import mailbox
for message in mailbox.mbox('"my downloaded gmail archive'):
    subject = message['subject']       # Could possibly be None.
    if subject and 'python' in subject.lower():
        print subject
```

But the problem now is that I'm stuck and I don't know how the retrieve the list of ten most people I've been mailing to. So can please someone help me with my problem?

Comment: You need to parse contents of the `message['To']` for this.

Comment: Thanks you! Worked for me.